# Count Number of Cells with Invalid Data Validation Values

Tags: google-sheets

I've been scratching my head at this issue.  I have Google sheet with a Data Validation that uses a List from a Range that creates a Drop Down with values listed.

When I type something that isn't found in the list of possible options, it will return the error message saying 'Input must fall within specific range'

I have about a ton of these cells going across the sheet from F2:Z2

[image]

All I want to be able to do is count the amount of cells that return this type of error message.

I've tried using COUNTIF, but I am not trying to found instances of a specific text in the box, I'm trying to count the amount of cells that don't pass validation.

I've also tried doing...

```
=COUNT(IF(ISERROR(F2:Z2),1,""))
```

However, apparently Sheets doesn't count it as an actual error?

Answer (score 1):

The `iserror()` function will only return `true` when the cell contains an error value. Your drop-down list cells do not contain error *values* but values like `Junior Technician 3rd Grade`.

To count the values that do not appear in the validation list, compare them directly to the range that holds the allowed values, like this:

`=counta( iferror( filter( F2:Z2, isna(match(F2:Z2, DropDownLists!A2:A, 0)) ) ) )`